# Override ValidationAttributes on a derived ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an instance in an MVC2 application where the only difference between two views is a slightly different range validation check on the same field. In an effort to keep the application as DRY as possible, I'm wondering if it's possible to override the validation attribute somehow.

I've tried to have a derived ViewModel that overrides the property and implements the range check differently like so:

```
public class Base
{
    [Range(1, 100)]
    public virtual int SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    [Range(2, 100)]
    public override int SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

however when I try that the MVC clientside validation still seems to continue to pick up the base class's validation attribute rather than the derived one.

I know there is a line of thought that says that I should have an entirely different ViewModel and never inherit, but it just feels so wrong. I'd be duplicating the View, ViewModel and logic to populate it.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and I think it's silly that we are forced to duplicate the views and models. What did you end up doing in the end?

Comment: I agree entirely. Still, I think I ended up doing just that; duplicating the ViewModels.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known issue:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/483001/in-asp-net-mvc-generic-try-updatemodel-methods-ignore-subtype-properties

> Thank you for reporting this issue. This is a deliberate design decision with the model binding feature of ASP.NET MVC. To override the type that gets used you can specify an explicit type when you call UpdateModel and TryUpdateModel:
>       UpdateModel(model);
>   When you leave out the type the compiler will use its type inference logic to guess the type that you meant. In this case it makes a guess that is incorrect.

(Without testing myself) I suggest trying to type cast into the subtype during binding and see if that would force it into recognizing the attribute.

Comment: The clientside validation is failing to recognise the attribute, so presumably this happens before binding occurs.